# Remove features with too little variation

Tags: algorithms, time-series-analysis

I have the following messy chart;
[image]

As you can see some features are very stable through the time series (post-2011) like Extraversion.
Is there an algorithm to remove features that do not have much variation compared to the other features?

Comment: Is there are reason that "compute the sample range of each time series and drop the ones with max-minus-min below some threshold" is not acceptable?

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to calculate this threshold? It seems arbitrary.

Comment: If you just have the one dataset, I would recommend just producing several charts with different threshold values and using the chart that makes you happiest.

Comment: An approach from a different angle may be simpler: *What are the five features featuring most variance?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. Identify a measure of variation for a feature.

Step 2. Remove all features for which this measure is below some threshold (or is below that of msot other features).

There are many [measures of variability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion) that you could use in step 1: standard deviation, [interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range), range (max minus min), [median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation), and more.  Any of these are probably reasonable.